Inverse Kinematics Pole Target Issues
I tried to follow multiple tutorials, but they always turn out wrong. I tried to set up this IK arm rig, but it points in the opposite direction. Adjusting the pole angle doesn't seem to help, as it just twists the arm unnaturally. No matter how I set it up, something always goes wrong as soon as I add the pole target. What is going wrong here?

Download .blend

Bend the elbow a bit in Edit mode so that Blender knows how it is supposed to bend:

